# How to change to BooleanField after True to False every month in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-celery-beat

**Info**: When i create a new customer i want to make `pending_customer` True which i set with Default value True so it's working fine and after the month the `pending_customer` make to false automatically.

I also try to make function `get_pending_customer` who could do it i know this is not the way to what i want to do. It's like a task based funcion which is automatically make `pending_customer` field True to false after the month. i want to know how can I do this?

Can anyone tell me what is the best way to do this?

models.py

```
from django.utils.timezone import datetime

class Customer(models.Model):
    """Customer Model"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    pending_customer = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    """Example""" # I know it's wrong way

    def get_pending_customer(self):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        month = datetime.timedelta(30)
        after_month = today + month
        if after_month:
            panding = self.object
            panding.pending_payment = False
            panding.save()
        return today
```

Comment: do you need to reset the pending_customer to True after one month? or is it completely dependent on created_on field??

Comment: @umair i just want the pending_customer get False after one month. Ignore this created_on it's a today date

Comment: Please take a look my question is updated!

Comment: Seems like you need a sceduler and n extra field with the date it sould be turned

Comment: yes i need sceduler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you use [custom-management-commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Write your code in a python file and put it in cron to run every day at a certain time. In the program look for objects older than 30 days and update them for your use case.

Project structure:

```
App_Name/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            update_old_data_moreover_30_days.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

It's your `update_old_data_moreover_30_days.py` file:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
    from App_Name.models import Customer 
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        Customer.objects.filter(created_on__lte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=30)).update(pending_customer=False)
        self.stdout.write('Updated customers older than 30 days')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of scheduling a task, you can annotate the `QuerySet` with a boolean field that is `True` if the user has registered less than 30 days ago.

You can annotate the objects with a `BooleanField` that is the result of a condition with an
[**`ExpressionWrapper`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper):

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Now

class CustomerManager(models.Model):

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).annotate(
            pending_customer=ExpressionWrapper(
                Q(created_on__gte=Now()-timedelta(days=30)),
                output_field=BooleanField()
            )
        )
```

In our model, we thus can omit the `pending_customer` field, and determine it by need. The model thus looks like:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    """Customer Model"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # no pending customer field
    # pending_customer = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = CustomerManager()

    @classmethod
    def get_pending_customers(cls):
        cls.objects.filter(pending_customer=True)
```

We can then access the pending customers with `Customer.get_pending_customers()`.